# Error in initializing a java.sql.Date

Tags: java, date, datetime, jdeveloper

I am creating a project in JDeveloper, based on EJB. I have a feature that inserts a date in the Oracle database, so I want to test it if it works correctly.
I have a test method with the following statement in it:

```
java.sql.Date sDate = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

In debug mode, I go to the variable and see that the value for cdate is null, whereas the fasttime field is filled with a number of type long(144...). 
[[image]]

I am wondering why there is mismatch. Is it a bug or I have made a mistake? Is not the date created with the current date and time by default?

Any ideas?

Comment: Share some code related to your DB insert - the statement you gave does not even include cDate

Comment: sDate - > cdate = null, fastTime = 14..... (please, see the picture in the post)

Comment: Of course you know that you're using two different types of Date?

Comment: I tried to use only one type - java.sql.Date, but there is no improvemnet

Comment: Why are you worried about private fields? Is it actually causing a bug? Voting to close until you list an actual bug.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

> public class Date extends Date A thin wrapper around a millisecond
>   value that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value. A
>   milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have
>   passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT.
>
> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values
>   wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting
>   the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the
>   particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

Comment: Would you like to give me an example?